# If Jesus was crucified among the malefactors, why didn't the soldiers probe him after the first malefactor? [adjusted]

Tags: jesus

> So the soldiers came and broke the legs of the two men who had been crucified[cs] with Jesus,[ct] first the **one** and *then* the **other**.[cu]. But when **they came** to Jesus and saw that he was already dead, they did not break his legs.  John 19:32-33 NET@

> Two rebels were crucified with him, one on his **right** and one on his **left**. Matthew 27:38 NET@

Wasn't Jesus supposed to be the second to be found by the soldiers?

Comment: I don't understand your question. It clearly says they could see that he was already dead.

Comment: The text gives the reason - Jesus was already dead.

Answer (score 3):

First, the reason for braking their legs was to speed up their death so that it would be before the Sabbath.  On the cross they had to push up with their legs to breath.

> 31 Since it was the day of Preparation, and so that the bodies would not remain on the cross on the Sabbath (for that Sabbath was a high day), the Jews asked Pilate that their legs might be broken and that they might be taken away.
> (John 19:31, ESV)

Thus, it makes sense that the solders would go to the ones pushing up with their legs and exhibiting life first since they would last the longest before dying.  With Jesus slouched down motionless, they instantly knew he was close to death at the very least because he could not last long without breathing.  When the soldiers got to Jesus, the spear verified that Jesus was already dead.

That's all I can say.  We cannot document any more that what is in these verses.  While John seems to indicate the order of the legs of the two thieves broken before Jesus is pierced, we cannot even guarantee John meant to specify this order of the soldier's actions.

Also see https://www.bibleversestudy.com/johngospel/john19-broken-legs.htm

Comment: At first the soldiers did not know whether the three were dead or alive. And the order not to leave the bodies on the crosses due to Easter was valid for the three crucified.

Comment: I edited my answer since you didn't seem to catch on that it wasn't that difficult from a distance to see that a crucified person was already dead.

Answer (score 2):

> Wasn't Jesus supposed to be the second to be found by the soldiers?

The three were close together; they didn't have to be *found*; they could all be seen at the same time.

This description of events doesn't necessarily indicate a strict temporal order.

The introductory word "But" can indicate an exception to what preceded.

One could read it as:

```
They broke the legs.
    But not Jesus though, because he was was no longer alive.
        But dead, because he had been speared through the spleen and stomach.
```

In chronological order:

- A soldier spears Jesus.
- Jesus is now obviously dead.
- Only the other two receive the standard treatment.

---

This order is much more explicit in Matthew's gospel.

Most translations omit a verse between Matthew 27:49 and 50, which RSV for example supplies in a footnote:

> <sup>49</sup>But the others said, "Wait, let us see whether Eli'jah will come to save him."
> <sup>[fn]</sup>And another took a spear and pierced his side, and out came water and blood
> <sup>50</sup>And Jesus cried again with a loud voice and yielded up his spirit.

and the NWT supplies inline:

> <sup>49</sup>But the rest of them said: “Let him be! Let us see whether Eli'jah comes to save him.” [[Another man took a spear and pierced his side, and blood and water came out.]]
> <sup>50</sup>Again Jesus creid out with a loud voice, and yielded up [his] spirit.
> — *[footnote] This sentence is contained in אBC and other important manuscripts, but is omitted by ADVgSy<sup>s.p.h</sup>Arm.*

From an hermeneuical perspective, clearly Jesus was alive when the spear entered his side, and he died almost immediately thereafter.

That he didn't die of "a broken heart" or some other cause is also obvious from a theological perspective.

From beginning to end, the Hebrew scriptures deal with the concept of life being in the blood, with death by exsanguination being necessary for sacrifices for atonement.

The Greek scriptures continue with the same theme, which was all along a type for Jesus's supreme sacrifice:

- Col 1:14 and Eph 1:7 each say "*In whom we have redemption through his blood*".
- Mat 26:28 says "*For this is my blood of the new testament, which is shed for many for the remission of sins.*".
- Heb 9:22 says "*And almost all things are by the law purged with blood; and without shedding of blood is no remission.*".

If Jesus hadn't died by bleeding to death, his sacrifice would have been unworthy, and there would be no salvation for mankind.

---

There are many publications discussing this in far greater detail, such as:

- [The Physical Death of Jesus Christ | Catholic Culture](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/view.cfm?id=252)
- [How, exactly, did Jesus Christ die?](https://www.eternalgod.org/q-a-6149/)
- [How Did Christ Die?](https://pcg.church/articles/224/how-did-christ-die)

Comment: Thank you, you answered masterfully.

Comment: Jesus did not die by the spear!  This answer is greatly misleading.

Comment: @Biblasia says "*Jesus did not die by the spear!*". So how did he die if it wasn't through loss of blood? Even animal sacrifices had to die by bleeding to death. And if he died some other way, there is no salvation. Col 1:14 and Eph 1:7 each say "*In whom we have redemption through his blood*".

Comment: Jesus died of a broken heart--anguished by the sins of the world, which had been laid on him, having separated him from the Father's presence.  This is evidenced by the issue of _both_ blood and water when the spear entered his _side_ (not his heart).  Jesus died well before the spear entered him, and it was because criminals usually lasted longer that the spear was inserted at all--just to test whether or not he was really dead already, which he was.  It was the sin of the world that killed Jesus, not the spear, nor even the nails.

Comment: @Biblasia says that "*Jesus died of a broken heart*".  Where did you get this idea from? The three references I added to the answer are from very different denominations, and they all agree that it was the spear.

Comment: @RayButterworth Perhaps you might like to inquire as to which denominations other commenters and answerers here represent, as they all agree that Jesus died prior to the spear.  You are the only one here saying it was the spear.  Ask a coroner how an issue of both blood and water would be possible.  The Bible gives us this detail for a reason, and it is more than just its symbolic value representing cleansing.  Consider the drops of _blood_ sweat in the Garden of Gethsemane--what level of anguish would this require?  (See Luke 22:44.)

Comment: @Biblasia says "*Ask a coroner how an issue of both blood and water would be possible*" — The spleen is located just to the left of the stomach. It bleeds profusely when ruptured, and the cheap wine that Jesus had just drunk (verse 48) could have provided the "water" when his stomach was torn open.

Comment: @Biblasia says "*you might like to inquire as to …*". Why don't you save us time and just tell us? "*they all agree that Jesus died prior to the spear. You are the only one here saying it was the spear.*". No, Matthew said it too, long before I did. The first link I provided above is from "Catholic Culture". When Catholics and Jehovah's Witnesses agree on something, it's got to be extremely fundamental to Christianity. ¶ You haven't answered where the "broken heart" idea comes from, nor explained how people can be saved by an improper sacrifice.